# Disable automatic CSRF verification and switch to manual

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using the CodeIgniter's core CSRF library, It's working fine however there are so many places where i don't need CSRF like API calls and callbacks, Is there anyway to disable the library from automatically verifying `POST` requests and have me manually specify whether i want to verify or not.

Example:

```
$this->security->verify_csrf();
```

P.S. i actually modified the security class and i got it working, but i prefer a solution that just extends the core instead of hard coding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not extend the Security class?

```
<?php

class MY_Security extends CI_Security {
    public function csrf_verify()
    {
        $bypass_csrf = TRUE; // some logic to bypass csrf goes here
        if ($bypass_csrf)
        {
            return $this->csrf_set_cookie();
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::csrf_verify();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same problem, what I ended up doing was disabling global CSRF verification and doing it in the controller.

So in my application/config/config.php, I set

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

In my custom controller (application/core/MY_Controller.php) I have an attribute to control csrf_protection like so:

```
class MW_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    var $csrf_protection = TRUE; // on by default

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        if ($this->csrf_protection)
        {
            $this->security->csrf_verify();
        }
    }
    ....
```

My other controllers extend MY_Controller, so I can just set $csrf->protection false as I need. For instance, my Auth controller disables CSRFchecks:

```
class Auth extends My_Controller {
    var $csrf_protection = FALSE; // don't need CSRF during login
    ....
```

Hope that helps, it gets the job done without hacking the core.

Comment: Sorry to bump this post but I came across this, implemented it and unfortunately what happens is that when csrf is enabled, it shows the csrf error every time a form is submitted! Any ideas what might be happening?

Comment: Seems CI isn't generating the csrf cookie or hidden form element.